# ScrollViewer Focus doesn't change to outer control

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I have used ListBox inside TreeView

```
        <TreeView Height="300">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item1"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item2">
                <ListBox Height="100">
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item1"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item2"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item3"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item4"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item5"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item6"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item7"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item8"/>
                </ListBox>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item3">
                <ListBox Height="100">
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item1"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item2"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item3"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item4"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item5"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item6"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item7"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Item8"/>
                </ListBox>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item4">
                <ListBox />
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item5">
                <ListBox />
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item6"/>
        </TreeView>
```

When I point the mouse point in ListBox and start scrolling the ListBox get scrolled. When the Scrolling gets end I need to change the focus to TreeView scroll viewer so, that TreeView get scroll. In this code the scrolling doesn't work for TreeView when mouse is inside ListBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I need to change the focus to outer control scroll viewer when after ListBox get scrolled*

This is *not* a good description of your problem, but if you are saying that you want to be able to move focus from inside the `ListBox` to outside the `ListBox`, then it seems that all you need is to learn how to navigate a `ListBox` from a keyboard using the arrow keys.

If focus is on a `TreeViewItem` that has a `ListBox` in it, then you can press the right arrow key to expand the item and iterate through the `ListBoxItem`s. You can then press the up and down arrow keys to select the previous or next items in the `ListBox`.

Once you have finished looking through the `ListBoxItem`s, you can then press the left arrow key to navigate back to the `TreeViewItem` from the `ListBox`. You will then be able to press the up and down arrow keys to navigate through the `TreeViewItem`s once again.

If that has not helped you with your problem, then please edit your question and add a clear description of your problem.

---

UPDATE >>>

You can detect when a `ListBox` has been scrolled to the bottom by handling the [`ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrollchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Days}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
    ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="ListBox_ScrollChanged" />
```

...

```
private void ListBox_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)e.OriginalSource;
    if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + scrollViewer.ViewportHeight == 
        scrollViewer.ExtentHeight)
    {
        // The ListBox was scrolled to the bottom
    }
}
```

Then, you can focus the next UI element using the [`TraversalRequest` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.traversalrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [UIElement.MoveFocus method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.movefocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
TraversalRequest request = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
UIElement focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
if (focusedElement != null) focusedElement.MoveFocus(request);
```

Comment: Thanks Sheridan, I have edited my query. I don't want to use keyboard i need navigation through scrolling

Comment: Then perhaps you should have asked your question more carefully.